# Deleting the first <br> after each </ul>

Tags: javascript

I'd like a javascript that deletes the first instance of `<br>` after each instance of `</ul>` AND only if `<br>` comes immediately after a `</ul>` tag. So far, I know how to replace `<br>` with nothing, but I'm not sure where to take the code from here.

```
    $('.section').each(function() {
        var string = $(this).html();    
        $(this).html(string.replace('<br>' , ''));  
    });
```

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you have `</ul></ul><br><br>`? Should both `<br>`'s be removed?

Comment: Nope, only the first <br> should be removed. Thanks

Comment: What if you have `<table> <tr> <td><ul><li>foo</li></ul></td> </tr> <tr> <td>bar<br>baz</table>`? Should the `<br>` be removed?

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question.

Comment: oh, ok. I'll try some of the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query selector `'.section ul + br'` and then on each `br` use `el.remove()`

It can be done like this:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', e => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.section ul + br')).forEach(br => {
    br.remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<p><input type="button" value="Remove br's"></p>

<div class="section">
  <ul><li>Text 1</li></ul><br><br>
  <ul><li>Text 2</li></ul><br>
  <ul><li>Text 3</li></ul><br><br>
  <ul><li>Text 4</li></ul><br>
</div>
```

Comment: That selector removes only adjacent siblings, not `<br>` in general.

Comment: This will only delete the `<br>` if it comes *immediately* after the `</ul>`. OP wants code that deletes the first occurrence of `<br>` after `</ul>`, so this wouldn't work for `</ul><p></p><br>`.

Comment: That is what the question is asking

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I disagree.

Comment: I then think the OP needs to elaborate more then since we are all interpreting the question differently.

Comment: Thanks but correct answer is as follows:  $('ul').next('br').remove();. Someone made this comment and then deleted it.

Comment: My answer and samuellawrentz answer should do just that.

Comment: @JasonHoward That is not the correct answer. That'll match the same elements as `ul + br`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.section ul+br').remove();
```

Here we are removing all the `br` that comes immediately after `ul`. This is just adjacent sibling CSS Selector.

Comment: Maybe remove the `.section` if you execute this code already on your `.section`s

Answer (score -1):

The following code works 100% for me and is very simple. The person who posted this answer deleted it seconds later for some reason.

```
$('ul').next('br').remove();
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as samuellawrentz's answer, which you said "doesn't work".

Comment: I'd remove my downvotes on some of the answers but it's too late: You can only change your vote after an edit of the answer itself, but the thing that's changed is not the answer, but the question. You made substantial changes after the first answers were posted.

Comment: im sorry for the confusion i caused. ill try to be more clear next time.